# What is this helvetica-like font called?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

The font is used in [this dribbble post](https://dribbble.com/shots/4114090-University-of-Utah-College-of-Pharmacy-Homepage) for the headlines and titles, not the body text.

[image]

So far I have tried multiple font identification sites but none gave a satisfactory result. Neue Haas Grotesk is the font that I've found so far to be the closest.

For me, the following things are important:

- The leg of the "R" is straight
- the dot on the "i" is round
- the ends of the "s" and "S" are fully or almost horizontal

Comment: Why not [ask the designer](https://twitter.com/chasingmack)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font is San Francisco Display.

The main text is the Heavy weight while the + is the Bold weight.

[image]

All 21 weights can be downloaded for free from [here](https://github.com/AppleDesignResources/SanFranciscoFont).

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be [Sailec](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typedynamic/sailec/), which is very nice, or Graphik from Commercial Type which has a ton of widths and languages supported.

As people have said, this is San Francisco Display. It has a detailed license, but in summary Apple **only** permits its use on Apple hardware and for related development (mockups and so on)–you can't host this as a webfont except to call it if viewing a webpage on an Apple device. Whoever did this webpage is mocking up what it would look like on an iPad or Mac–on a Windows computer they'd have to choose another font.

Answer (score 0):

Roboto is pretty good, and a Google font to boot: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto

Comment: Roboto fails on many letters. Notably the spur on the a and the e and o shape.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably Inter with a lesser letter Spacing.
See [Inter](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter?query=inter) or [Inter-Tight](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter+Tight?query=inter).